# How can i store columns dynamically in SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in Android development.Please help me How can i store columns name in Sqlite database dynamically.

Create database below here:

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL(
  "create table contacts " +
  "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)"
  );
}
```

And insert query below here:

```
 public boolean insertContact  (String name, String phone, String email,String street,String place)                                     
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put("name", name);
  contentValues.put("phone", phone);
  contentValues.put("email", email);    
  contentValues.put("street", street);
  contentValues.put("place", place);
  db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: you should not change the columns  name dynamically..you have to change the column names once that to need of changing it..change column values dynamically is not good .To change the columns name use ALTER command

Comment: @brahmyadigopula 1.suppose i have one textview. I can store it into database. 2.Suppose i increse two textview also in my .xml file then how can i store into Sqlite database Dynamically without change insert query.

Comment: you mean if you have more columns dynamically right?then you have to estimate the columns  and create the table for it ..while creating the table make columns default.and insert the values at your desired columns

Comment: @brahmyadigopula yes you are right.Is it possible?

Comment: yes bro..of course.it is possible..

Answer (score 1):

you can use ALTER TABLE function on your onUpgrade() method, like this :

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

// If you need to add a column
if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
}
}
```

Obviously, the SQLite will differ depending on the column definition

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide a value for every column in your table to insert a new row.  You can just change the code in your method to:

```
public long insertContact(ContentValues contentValues) {
    return db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
}
```

Let the calling function decide which values it wants to insert, which can be all, some or none of the available columns.  Any values not specified will be `null` in the table.  For example if calling function does:

```
EditText name, email;

// ...

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", name.getText().toString());
values.put("email", email.getText().toString());
insertContact(values);
```

will insert a new row in the database with "name" and "email" filled in and the rest of the columns `null`.